# Skipping equal numbers in VBA loop

Tags: vba, loops, transpose, skip

I am attempting to convert UAV coordinate data from XML to an excel table, which involves transposing three rows of coordinates in to one. The data is currently set out as follows [Column letters indicated in ()]:

```
(A)        (B)
Mark     Coordinate
1          -97.373773
1          124.34848
1          225
2          -97.746343
2          123.48343
2          225
3          -97.342533
3          123.23454
3          225
```

I would like to create a loop which copies all the coordinate and elevation data for each of the "mark" data and pastes it in to one line, as follows:

```
(A)        (B)           (C)            (D)
1         -97.373773    124.34848       225
2         -97.746343    123.48343       225
3         -97.342533    123.23454       225
```

Can someone give me some insight as to how to create a loop which will skip the duplicate "mark" numbers in the A Column, so that I can copy and paste the relevant info in to one row?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will transfer your two A:B columns over to the right in D:G.

```
Sub xfer_coords()
    Dim a As Long, r As Long, rw As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = a Then
                .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = _
                  .Cells(r, 2).Value
            Else
                a = .Cells(r, 1).Value
                rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(rw, 4) = a
                .Cells(rw, 5) = .Cells(r, 2).Value
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have stepped through the code and watch it populate the cells (flawlessly!), but cannot work out how it works! If you have a free moment, could you add a few comments as to how it does what it does?

Comment: Hmmm I think I may get it: it searches the mark column and if not yet added, adds it, if it has already been added, it adds the values of the three coordinates which correspond with the "mark" value, and loops through. I am 90% sure I am right. Many thanks again

Comment: @Chris Hall - That's pretty much it. When it finds a new *mark* it adds the *mark* to the first unused cell it can find in column D and the corresponding *coordinate* into the cell to the right (column E, same row). As it loops through the *mark* column, if the *mark* is the same, it shoves the *coordinate* value into the first unused cell to the right of the last *mark* used. If different, it starts the process anew.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary, from the MS Scripting Runtime Library to accomplish this, with your Mark as the key and a Collection as the value. To instantiate one:

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

And then to add values to it:

```
If Not dict.Exists(yourMark) Then
    Dim newCollection As Collection
    Set newCollection = New Collection
    newCollection.Add(yourValue)

    dict.Add yourMark, newCollection
Else
    dict(yourMark).Add(yourValue)
End If
```

That way, a new mark would only be added if it hadn't already been seen, and all values would be associated with that single mark.

You can also use dict.Item(mark) to fetch the Collection associated with any mark:

```
 Dim coordinates As Collection
 Set coordinates = dict.Item(mark)
```

And you can iterate through the dictionary like so:

```
For Each iterMark in dict.Keys
    Dim coordinates as Collection
    Set coordinates = dict.Item(iterMark)
Next
```

Here's the Microsoft Support article on the [Dictionary](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187234).

If for some reason that's not possible, there's also a way to use the Collection in a key-value fashion.

Comment: Many thanks for the swift reply. I have never heard of this before, so will look in to it. My thought process (base on a very limited looping knowledge), would be to set a variable to 0 and then having an if statement which checked whether the following "mark" number was the same as the previous, and if so, skipping to the next one which didn't - and so on... I just don't know enough about loops to code this, or indeed whether I am correct...!

Comment: @ChrisHall My pleasure! If it was helpful, please don't forget to check this as your selected answer.

Comment: @ChrisHall I thought about that for a second, but the problem is that you don't have any way of knowing how many marks you're going to encounter at runtime, nor necessarily what order they're in. For that reason, it's not really feasible to try to make variables for every single mark.

Comment: You are right that I will never know how many marks there will be, but each one will always have a lat, long and elevation (any more or less will be a problem!). Isnt it possible to stop a loop on the condition that the following row has no data? I am all for giving your idea a go, but suddenly found myself in a world of unknown!

Comment: @ChrisHall Oh, whatever way you were going to use to iterate through each row of your data doesn't have to change. For any given line, you can get the mark and coordinate however you want - as long as you have a mark, and a coordinate, you can just use the above code, and it'll result in a dictionary where all coordinates for any given mark are accessible by using dict.Item(key).

Comment: @ChrisHall I've added some more details to the question.